# Should I use Single Table Inheritence (STI) or single class logic to handle relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Model called Area. Area can be a type State, County, Town, or Building. All objects of Area whether they are State, County, Town, or Building have the same fields (Name, Description and Notes).

There is no function or behavior which is different between an Area of different types. The types are merely present to create relationships.

A State has Counties, a County has Towns etc. This is used to visually represent, organize and filter Areas. So a user can see a show view of an Area of type County and see a list of all Towns belonging to that County and also see the State that it belongs to. They can click the State it belongs to to then view all Counties in that State. They could also instead click on a Town and see all the Buildings in that Town.

Here's my Area schema:

```
create_table "areas", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.text     "notes"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "area_type"
  t.string   "type"
end
```

As you can see I am already experimenting with using both STI and a regular string (area_type). I haven't decided or figured out which one is best in this situation although from my research I'm leaning more toward using area_type instead of STI since there is no difference between the data model of any of the types.

Here's my Area.rb Model:

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self
    def area_types
      types_array = [
        ['State'],
        ['County'],
        ['Town'],
        ['Building']
      ]
    end
  end
end

class State < Area
  has_many :counties
end

class County < Area
  has_many :towns
  belongs_to :state
end

class Town < Area
  has_many :buildings
  belongs_to :county
end

class Place < Area
  belongs_to :town
end
```

I'm new at rails and struggling to make the right choices to build this correctly, any advice or help on this? Please be as specific as possible because I'm not super knowledgable about rails. I feel like I'm pretty close but just don't know how to wrap all the remaining pieces together. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but personally I would keep this as simple as possible - remove the `Area` concept and just create individual models (each with their own database table) - the fact that they share `Name, Description and Notes` seems to be coincidental and not worth abstracting into STI, let State have a country_id and Town have a county_id

Comment: This would be creating 6 models of the exact same code which is pretty wet. I want to do it the clean way and keep it dry.

Comment: Dont make it so dry it chafes - http://podcasts.thoughtbot.com/giantrobots/24